# editLink is null when using youtube api to change a youtube video from private to public

Tags: video, youtube-api, gdata

I am trying to update a youtube video from private to public. But the editlink I got in respond is null.

Here's my code:

```
// returns a youtube service
GDataServiceGoogleYouTube *service = [self youtubeService];
[service setAuthToken:[self getRequestToken]];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/%@?v=2&key=%@", youtube_id, DEVELOPER_KEY]];
GDataServiceTicket *ticket;
ticket = [service fetchFeedWithURL:url delegate:self didFinishSelector:@selector(didFinishFetchingVideo:withEntry:error:)];
```

in callback, [videoEntry editLink] is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that only video entries from the [uploads feed](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_updating_and_deleting_videos) are editable. So you'd want to use the following URL pattern:

`https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads/%@?v=2&key=%@`